# Modify items in a database table

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have this SQLite database:

```
private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";

private static final String TABLE_NAME = "people_table";
private static final String COL1 = "_id";
private static final String COL2 = "Hour";
private static final String COL3 = "Minutes";
private static final String COL4 = "On_Off";
```

How cand I modify the value of the On_Off fom 1 -> 0 and  0 -> 1 Pseudocod:

```
public void OnAlarm()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL( "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL4 + "=1 ");

}
public void OffAlarm()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL( "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL4 + "=0 ");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`... WHERE` ... **what**? You miss the condition!

```
public void OnAlarm()
{
    // Change On_Off from 0 to 1
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL( "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL4 + " = 1 WHERE " + COL4 + " = 0");
}
public void OffAlarm()
{
    // Change On_Off from 1 to 0
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL( "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL4 + " = 0 WHERE " + COL4 + " = 1");

}
```

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: On_Off (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE people_table SET On_Off = 0 WHERE On_Off = 1

Comment: This is because you added that column later. Nothing to do with the SQL command.  Uninstall and reinstall your app and see it works perfectly. This is really the fundamentals of SQLite on Android.

Comment: You're welcome. Remember: **every time** you alter the structure of your database, this one has to be recreated. Either by uninstalling and reinstalling or by handlig the DATABASE_VERSION constant.